# Send message to whatsapp using typescript and https

Tags: typescript, https

I want to send a message to the WhatsApp cloud API, using typescript, however, I get the error "Parameter implicitly has an 'any' type."
In nodejs it works perfectly for me, but I can't transcribe it in typscript.
It works in Nodejs, I share the code
`function sendMessageWhatsapp(data)
{

```
const options={
    host:"graph.facebook.com",
    path:"/v17.0/100215886340876/messages",
    method:"POST",
    body:data,
    headers:
    {
        
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${TOKEN_CLOUD_API_WSP}`
    }
};


const req=https.request(options,res=>{
  
    res.on("data",d=>{
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});


req.on("error",error=>{
    console.error(error)
});


req.write(data);


req.end();
```

}
`
However, in typescript I get an error
I share a screenshot

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWNUM.png)

I tried to add the parameter to be any, however, it keeps throwing me the error
`function sendMessageWhatsapp(data:any)
{

```
const options={
    host:"graph.facebook.com",
    path:"/v17.0/100215886340876/messages",
    method:"POST",
    body:data,
    headers:
    {
        
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.ACCES_TOKEN_FB}`
    }
};


const req=https.request(options,res:any=>{
  
    res.on("data",d=>{
        process.stdout.write(d);
    });
});


req.on("error",error:any=>{
    console.error(error)
});


req.write(data);


req.end();
```

}
`

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple minor issues going on here. It looks like you're using VS Code so it's likely you have a tsconfig.json file in your project which has a config option (probably `strict` or `noImplicitAny` set to `true`) and when the config is set like that, if TypeScript can't infer the type of an untyped variable, it complains that "Parameter *so-and-so* implicitly has an 'any' type." because your config says to do that.

So you could go remove the config option that's causing it, but if you're going to go that route then why are you even using TypeScript?

The better choice is to find out the types of those un-typed parameters and add them in.

As an example, eyeballing it, the fix for line 22:
 `const req=https.request(options,res=>{`

is to add a typing for`res` of `http.IncomingMessage` which I *think* will then automatically remove the error on line 24 because TypeScript will then be able to infer that `d` has a type of `(chunk: any) => void`. Repeat the process for line 30 and your problems are (almost) done. BTW, I'm using [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/node/v18) as a reference for my types.

That leaves only one small issue which is that when you pass an anonymous arrow function as a parameter which itself either takes more than one parameter or takes even one typed parameter, then the parameters need to be enclosed in parentheses. Put another way, parentheses are only not required if you have exactly one un-typed parameter.

So line 22 should look something like
 `const req = https.request(options, (res: http.IncomingMessage) => {`
and line 30 like
 `req.on("error", (error: Error) => {`

Examples that will fail are:
 no parameter  `=> {`       needs to be `() => {`
 one typed   `s: string => {`   needs to be `(s: string) => {`
 typed+non  `n, s: string => {`  needs to be `(n, s: string) => {`

With the information I can see, I think these changes should set you right.